# Converting a date to a time in Java

Tags: java, datetime

How can one convert a date type into a time type in Java?

Comment: You're going to need to provide *much* more information than that. Are you talking about databases? java.util.Date? Some other type? What's the "time" type?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming based on your question history you want convert [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to [`java.sql.Time`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html). You can just [construct](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#Time%28long%29) `Time` with the milliseconds as obtained from [`Date#getTime()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29):

```
Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
```

Also see the linked Javadocs. This is #1 source to look for answers to this kind of trivial questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object stores date and time, you can get the time out of a date with accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

```
DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Zurich"));
Date a = dfm.parse("2007-02-26 20:15:00");
Date b = dfm.parse("2007-02-27 08:00:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

If date is a Date object, then use:

```
Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Date and time classes can be a bit confusing. I wrote a tutorial covering the core classes. You can find it here:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/index.html